# Can I have create an InnoDB table without a PK? If so, would a secondary index be used as the clustered index?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, innodb, clustered-index, database-indexes

Is it possible to create an InnoDB table without a Primary Key?

Since InnoDB tables are structured as clustered index around the PK, what would be the structure of a table without PK? Would that table still be a clustered index, but around a secondary key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysqldocs/v50/storage-engines.html#innodb-table-and-index

#### 14.2.13. InnoDB Table and Index Structures

> If you do not define a PRIMARY KEY for your table, MySQL picks the first UNIQUE index that has only NOT NULL columns as the primary key and InnoDB uses it as the clustered index. **If there is no such index in the table, InnoDB internally generates a clustered index where the rows are ordered by the row ID** that InnoDB assigns to the rows in such a table. The row ID is a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted. Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in insertion order.